# The conditions for Harmonics functions in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, self-learning, harmonic-functions

Let $\sigma(u, v)$ and $\gamma(u, v)$ be harmonic functions on a region $D$ in $\Bbb C$.

What are the conditions on $\sigma$ and $\gamma$ such that $\sigma \gamma$ is harmonic on $D$.

And I want to prove that these conditions hold when $\sigma + i\gamma$ is analytic on $D$. Or I want to Show that when $\sigma \gamma$ is harmonic, it does not necessarily imply that $\sigma + i\gamma$ is analytic on D.

---

I have just been studying the topics. Therefore, please explain this at the high level knowledge. And please be explanatory:) and also, Honestly I dont have enough correct idea. So I cannot wrote. Please help me solving the question. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $w = f(z) = \sigma +i\gamma$ is holomorphic where $\sigma$ and $\gamma$ are (real-valued) harmonic functions on a region $D$ in $\mathbb{C}$, then $w^2$ will also be holomorphic on $D$. But $w^2 = \sigma^2 - \gamma^2 +2i\sigma\gamma$, and the real and imaginary parts of any holomorpic function are certainly harmonic. Thus we can conclude in this case that $\sigma\gamma$ is a (real) harmonic function in $D$.

Additionally, (changing your notation slightly), to show that $\sigma\gamma$ being harmonic does not necessarily imply that $\sigma + i\gamma$ is holomorphic in $D$, consider $\sigma(x,y) = x$ and $\gamma(x,y)=-y$. Both of these are harmonic, and $\sigma\gamma = -xy$ is also harmonic, as can be seen by finding $\Delta \sigma, \Delta\gamma, \Delta(\sigma\gamma)$. However $\sigma+i\gamma = x-iy$ which is a standard example of a non-analytic function.

For the conditions for $\sigma\gamma$ to be harmonic, given that $\sigma$ and $\gamma$ are harmonic without using Maple, you can do the following (I am simply expanding the answer by user64494 here!):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\sigma\gamma) = \frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial x}\gamma+\sigma\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial x}$$

so that

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(\sigma\gamma) = \frac{\partial^2\sigma}{\partial x^2}\gamma+\sigma\frac{\partial^2\gamma}{\partial x2} + 2\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial x}\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial x}$$

Now do the same for $y$ and add the two results and use the fact that $\sigma$ and $\gamma$ are harmonic to get the result that $\sigma\gamma$ will be harmonic if

$$\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial x}\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial y}\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial y} = 0$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Dear John, explained well. But please can you complete all of the answer? Can you write other conditions? The user64494's answer is not understandable for me because it is so high level. And I dont know maple code. Your explanation is precisely my level. I want to Accept your answer :)

Comment: @B11b If you are not happy with Maple, then just work out $\partial(\sigma\gamma)/\partial x$ then $\partial^2(\sigma\gamma)/\partial x^2$ and the same for $\partial(\sigma\gamma)/\partial y$ then $\partial^2(\sigma\gamma)/\partial y^2$, and use the fact that $\Delta \sigma = 0$.

Comment: I asked one thing. Is the another answer and your answer both enough to explain pricesely and perfectly the question?

Comment: I asked user64494 but she/he insistently explained the maple code. I dont want to learn it. And I really dont understand these answers are enough. What do I need to add more info to the answer to complete its answer... :(

Comment: I never heared laplacian..etc. before. And I dont want to learn. I just want to learn itsanswer to comprehend the topic. And your answer seems so close to me. Please continue:)

Comment: How to find $\Delta \sigma$ $\Delta \gamma$ $\Delta (\sigma \gamma)$?

Comment: Really thank you so much:) I distrubed you.

Answer (score 2):

The Maple code $$ with(VectorCalculus):
local(gamma); simplify(Laplacian(sigma(u, v)*gamma(u, v), [u, v])=0, {Laplacian(gamma(u, v), u, v]) = 0, Laplacian(sigma(u, v), [u, v]) = 0});
 $$ outputs $$2\, \left( {\frac {\partial }{\partial u}}\sigma \left( u,v \right) 
 \right) {\frac {\partial }{\partial u}}{\it \gamma} \left( u,v
 \right) +2\, \left( {\frac {\partial }{\partial v}}\sigma \left( u,v
 \right)  \right) {\frac {\partial }{\partial v}}{\it \gamma} \left( u,
v \right)=0. 
  $$ We find the Laplacian of $\sigma\gamma$, using the rules of the differentiation and taking into account that the Laplacians $\Delta \sigma=0$ and $\Delta \gamma=0.$ Maple helps to avoid a routine work to this end. 
The Cauchy-Riemann conditions $$ \frac {\partial\sigma}{ \partial u}=\frac {\partial\gamma}{ \partial v},\frac {\partial\sigma}{ \partial v}= -\frac {\partial\gamma}{ \partial u}$$ clearly imply that condition, but not vice versa. Therefore, if $\sigma+ i\gamma$ is analytical on $D$, then $\sigma\gamma$ is harmonic in $D$, but not vice versa.

PS. The Maple code $$local(gamma); diff(sigma(u, v)*gamma(u, v), u, u)+diff(sigma(u, v)*gamma(u, v), v, v)  $$outputs $$ \left( {\frac {\partial ^{2}}{\partial {u}^{2}}}\sigma \left( u,v
 \right)  \right) {\it \gamma} \left( u,v \right) +2\, \left( {\frac {
\partial }{\partial u}}\sigma \left( u,v \right)  \right) {\frac {
\partial }{\partial u}}{\it \gamma} \left( u,v \right) +\sigma \left( u
,v \right) {\frac {\partial ^{2}}{\partial {u}^{2}}}{\it \gamma}
 \left( u,v \right) + \left( {\frac {\partial ^{2}}{\partial {v}^{2}}}
\sigma \left( u,v \right)  \right) {\it \gamma} \left( u,v \right) +2\,
 \left( {\frac {\partial }{\partial v}}\sigma \left( u,v \right) 
 \right) {\frac {\partial }{\partial v}}{\it \gamma} \left( u,v
 \right) +\sigma \left( u,v \right) {\frac {\partial ^{2}}{\partial {v
}^{2}}}{\it \gamma} \left( u,v \right) 
 ,$$ i.e. the Laplacian of $\sigma\gamma.$ It remains to apply  $\Delta \sigma=0$ and $\Delta \gamma =0$.

Comment: That's thanks to The Cauchy-Riemann conditions $$ \frac {\partial\sigma}{ \partial u}=\frac {\partial\gamma}{ \partial v},\frac {\partial\sigma}{ \partial v}= -\frac {\partial\gamma}{ \partial u}$$, I can reach the above output you wrote by the maple code. That's, without the maple code, I can find the output with the cauchy riemann conditions. Right?

Comment: Well, is your answer completely enough to show all of my solution?

Comment: If there is not enough, please complete your answer. I cannot even see that the answer is completed or not:( I asked this question to learn well. Please can you help me little bit more.